# Data pull and push

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, observer-pattern, job-scheduling

I am writing a .NET window service which schedules job in certain interval. I am using QUARTZ for scheduling. A job will do 2 tasks:

1. Pull data using some SDK from one data source.
2. Push retrieved data to some other data source using REST APIs.

Pulling data is time consuming and I will pull in chunks and push the same.

My question is mostly on design side on the component who sits between push and pull. I want to notify push component when something becomes available for push.

Please let me know opinions on job queue, observer?

Answer (score 0):

I would you use an *[hexagonal](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture)* approach. In details:

- the Quartz job would be an object that completely delegates the work to a dedicated *use case* object (e.g. *NotifyExtractedData*, probably you can think of a better name...) in order to avoid coupling between Quartz details and your business logic;
- *NotifyExtractedData* object would depend upon two interfaces that represent the *ports* of the *hexagon*: may be *IDataGateway* and *INotifationGateway*
- *IDataGateway* could have a method `Chunk GetChunk();` The implementation of this interface could be an object that represent the *hexagon* adapter to the SDK: *SDKDataGateway*. Inside this object I would put all the logic of data extraction using the SDK. *Chunk* would be a DTO that contains the data chunk of your extraction;
- *INotificationGateway* interface could have a method `void Notify(Chunk chunck);` that receives the data chunk extracted by your data gateway. The implementation of the *INotificationGateway* interface could be an object *RESTNotificationGateway* that contains all the details about REST API you need to use to notify data.

This is only a raw idea of a possible solution. The names could be improved for sure. I hope it could help you.